# connection between angular and nodejs file

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a front end application developed in angular and I have a nodejs file that collects data from a simulator.What steps do i have to do so i can access data from that nodejs file in my angular app?I am new to these kind of connections.

//nodejs file

```
var ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial");
var client = new ModbusRTU();

client.connectTCP("127.0.0.1", { port: 502 });
client.setID(1);
console.log("conected");
setInterval(function() {
    client.readHoldingRegisters(0, 10, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data.data);
});
```

}, 1000);

Comment: If you're looking for real-time data, perhaps look into something like https://socket.io/ - I use this for my applications.

Comment: This question is overly broad to provide a definitive answer. You could send the data through ajax or websockets depending of the needs

Answer (score 0):

you can either save it on any database if you need else just save it on any variable.
create a route in nodejs and make a HTTP call from angular then in that route return the value.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('your result data here')
})
```